# CSS: min-width responsiveness inside iframe

Tags: css, iframe, responsive-design

I am using CSS @media tag and max-width. The requirement is to have smaller text size on large screens, and bigger text size on mobile screens. So at a basic level I have:

```
body {
    font-size: 13px;
 }

@media (max-width:991px){
    body{   
        font-size:24px;
    }
}
```

This works fine, but I have elements on screen that open iframes on the screen with widths smaller than 992px, so they will have a giant 24px font on them even on large screens. Is there a way I can make the max-width rule follow the screen width rather than the iframe width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specific your body with an id then style by this id like this:

```
<body id="mainBody">
...
</body>
@media (max-width:991px){
    #mainBody{   
        font-size:24px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. My application had a master page which caused all the iframes to have the same <body id="mainBody">. Your answer was helpful as I found the iframes open with html tag having class "ms-dialog". so I added this rule instead: html:not(.ms-dialog) > body{   
        font-size:24px;
    }

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery for that problem. you can use resize function just like this.

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    //this will get the default screen width
    var width = $(window).width(); //this will get the width of your screen.
        $("#iframeID").css({"width":width+"px"});

    //this is when you resize the screen
    $(window).resize(function(){
        width = $(this).width(); //this will get the width when you resize the screen.
        $("#iframeID").css({"width":width+"px"});

    });
});
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: While this might work, I still prefer a css only solution.